# Opencart Version 1.5.1.3 Installed on IIS 7. How can I get SEO Friendly URL's?

Tags: php, iis-7, seo, windows-server-2008, opencart

Im trying to generate SEO Friendly URL's for opencart in IIS 7. I have successfully installed a website, assigned a domain and connected the opencart installation to a mysql database instance.

Generating SEO Friendly URL's in apache seems so easy however I am paying for a windows server for asp development. Just wondering if anyone had any ideas on the issue?

Thanks. (Apologies if this has been answered but I haven't seen it anywhere)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help

http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=9693&p=46743

or

http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=16721

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can install URL Rewrite module for IIS 7 with the link http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite. Its Free!!

1.Download (x86 or x64)

2.Double click to install

3.Open IIS Manage and locate the Rewrite Module

4.Import the htaccess code and it convert automatically

**UNFORTUNATELY AM NOT ABLE TO UPLOAD IMAGES FOR BETTER UNDERSTANDING :(**

Tats it! Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: So far so good, however I had to comment RewriteBase / to get the import to work. Everything seems to work, however time will tell as this is the first time I am using opencart and working more than a few minutes with PHP.

Comment: The SEO urls for products and information links works however the other links still utilise the querystring

Comment: By default Opencart supports SEO url only for products,manufacturers, categories and information pages. All other will be query string. But you can change it buy using some extension.